# Eclipse PDT multiline array template

Tags: php, eclipse, configuration, formatting

when i type a new array like this:

```
return array(
    'test' => array()
);
```

and then inside inner arrays brackets when i enter newline, eclipse does something like that:

```
return array(
    'test' => array(
    // <- this indentation is made with tab instead of spaces
)
)
```

I have set space indentation in my eclipse, and it works well, but when it expends arrays brackets, id puts indentation made with tab character.

Also closing bracket is on wrong level of indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pdt 3.3.0 (eclipse lun RC2 now) problem with tabs and spaces are fixed.

Second problem - invalid indentation, is known bug (will be fixed in 3.3.1) - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=435798